# Error creating bean jpaMappingContext in spring boot

Tags: java, spring

i get this error and i don`t get it why , i just started to learn springframework by making a site .I added all the error maybe it will be more easy to help me because i really cant see why is this error, i have setters for autority. if anyone have any idea is ok , i deleted the   Can anyone help?

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepo' defined in com.deiutz.BuildIT.reposit.UserRepo defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jpaMappingContext' while setting bean property 'mappingContext'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaMappingContext': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:342) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:113) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1691) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1436) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:608) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:531) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:671) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:659) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.config.DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener.onApplicationEvent(DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener.java:53) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.config.DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener.onApplicationEvent(DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener.java:35) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:203) ~[spring-context-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:196) ~[spring-context-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:161) ~[spring-context-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:426) ~[spring-context-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:383) ~[spring-context-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:945) ~[spring-context-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:591) ~[spring-context-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:144) ~[spring-boot-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:767) ~[spring-boot-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) ~[spring-boot-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:426) ~[spring-boot-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:326) ~[spring-boot-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1309) ~[spring-boot-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1298) ~[spring-boot-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at com.deiutz.BuildIT.BuildItApplication.main(BuildItApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaMappingContext': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1788) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:609) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:531) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:330) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    ... 33 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:421) ~[spring-orm-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) ~[na:na]
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister
    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:123) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.23.Final.jar:5.4.23.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:77) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.23.Final.jar:5.4.23.Final]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.initialize(MetamodelImpl.java:181) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.23.Final.jar:5.4.23.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:301) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.23.Final.jar:5.4.23.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:469) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.23.Final.jar:5.4.23.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1259) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.23.Final.jar:5.4.23.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    ... 4 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to instantiate default tuplizer [org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer]
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:91) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.23.Final.jar:5.4.23.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructDefaultTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:116) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.23.Final.jar:5.4.23.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityMetamodel.<init>(EntityMetamodel.java:423) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.23.Final.jar:5.4.23.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.<init>(AbstractEntityPersister.java:608) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.23.Final.jar:5.4.23.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister.<init>(SingleTableEntityPersister.java:128) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.23.Final.jar:5.4.23.Final]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:96) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.23.Final.jar:5.4.23.Final]
    ... 12 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:88) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.23.Final.jar:5.4.23.Final]
    ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: Could not locate setter method for property [com.deiutz.BuildIT.security.Autority#authority]
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.ReflectHelper.findSetterMethod(ReflectHelper.java:635) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.23.Final.jar:5.4.23.Final]
    at org.hibernate.property.access.internal.PropertyAccessBasicImpl.<init>(PropertyAccessBasicImpl.java:44) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.23.Final.jar:5.4.23.Final]
    at org.hibernate.property.access.internal.PropertyAccessStrategyBasicImpl.buildPropertyAccess(PropertyAccessStrategyBasicImpl.java:27) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.23.Final.jar:5.4.23.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Property.getGetter(Property.java:311) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.23.Final.jar:5.4.23.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.buildPropertyGetter(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:193) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.23.Final.jar:5.4.23.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.<init>(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:147) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.23.Final.jar:5.4.23.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.<init>(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:53) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.23.Final.jar:5.4.23.Final]
    ... 28 common frames omitted
```

UserRepo:

```
    package com.deiutz.BuildIT.reposit;


import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.deiutz.BuildIT.User.User;

@Repository
public interface UserRepo extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

    User findByUsername(String username);

}


    package com.deiutz.BuildIT.User;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import com.deiutz.BuildIT.User.products.cos;
import com.deiutz.BuildIT.security.Autority;

@Entity
@Table(name = "Users")
public class User {

    private long id;
    private String Name;
    private String Username;
    private String password;
    private cos cosul;

    private Set<Autority> authorities = new HashSet<>();

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return Username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.Username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    public Set<Autority> getAuthorities() {
        return authorities;
    }

    public void setAuthorities(Set<Autority> authorities) {
        this.authorities = authorities;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        Name = name;
    }

}
    package com.deiutz.BuildIT.security;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;

import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;

import com.deiutz.BuildIT.User.User;

@Entity
public class Autority implements GrantedAuthority {


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 572078309935282677L;
    private Long id;
    private String autority;
    private User user;



    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @ManyToOne()
    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAuthority() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return autority;
    }

    public void setAutority(String autority) {
        this.autority = autority;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written in the error message :

Could not determine type for: com.deiutz.BuildIT.User.products.cos, at table: users, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(cos)]

You are using an attribute like this :

private cos cos;

Hibernate does not understand this type.
If this is not intended to be used in schema then mark it as :
@Transient

Comment: public void setAutority(String autority) 
There is a spelling mistake here. Hibernate uses reflection to find getters and setters so the spelling should be correct else it wont be able to find them.

Answer (score 0):

As written by Faizan, Hibernate doesn't know how to map the cos Type. Either don't persist it (@Transient) or define a Mapping - probably you want to save it as a JSON type, where hibernate-types https://github.com/vladmihalcea/hibernate-types can help. You can also create your schema at https://bootify.io, including the JSON type.

Comment: looks like a connection issue to the database